# component to measure the passing of a striped string

Tags: measurement, encoder

Has anyone ever come across some sort of optical component that can count the stripes in a patterned string as the string is pulled through?  Just curious if something like this exists or if the DIY route will be necessary.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the wider context, what are you trying to achieve - I mean you aren't just trying to design a circuit that blindly waits for string to come along (that happens to be striped) so you can count the stripes - you're actually trying to solve an engineering problem and if you "feed" us the application, you may get a better answer. Right?

Comment: Hah, right, there is indeed an engineering problem lurking.  I'm unspooling a weighted line into water and I want to know how far the line has traveled.  I could track the spool's revs, but I'm curious to see if there's a way to get a true measurement of the line itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is transparent (and least to infrared) except for the markings, you can use an [opto-interrupter](http://www.jameco.com/1/3/opto-interrupter):

[image: opto-interrupter]

It is essentially an [opto-isolator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) with a slot in the middle into which you can insert something to block the light from the photodiode to the phototransistor.

Comment: Could you use something like a tcrt1000 photo reflective sensor instead?

Comment: @carveone sure, though how well it works will depend on the nature of the string, and the markings, and the ambient light, and the associated circuitry. Same is true of the opto-interrupter.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be the first thing we try.  The line 0.5mm in diameter so I guess we will create some line-guides to keep it on the beam path.